# How can componentDidMount wait for a value from redux store before executing (without using setTimeout)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get the authentication info into React component and fetch data related to the authenticated user, but componentDidMount is not getting the auth value from the redux store unless setTimeOut is used.
How Do I go about it?

I tried componentWillReceiveProps() , but that does not work either .

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
   componentDidMount = () => {
         console.log(this.props.auth);
       setTimeout(
          () => console.log(this.props.auth),
          100
       )
   }
```

Only console.log within setTimeout returns the value

Comment: You probably need update hook.

Comment: when I use the update hook, I end up with infinite loop of getting the data and re-rendering the component..

Comment: You are calling Auth api in your componentWillMount, Right????

Comment: @DavitG You'll need to compare previous state.

Comment: @Prakash, componentWillMount too , not getting the auth value unless time delay is applied. Thank you

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, could you please give an example or explain further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue a while back and what helped me was to think about my component as a function.

What I would do is display a spinner, until auth is not null, then render a different view once it is ready.

```
    class Dashboard extends Component {    
       render = () => {
             if(this.props.auth === null){
                 return <SpinnerComponent />
             }

             return ....
       }
    }
```

What will happen is that:

- Before props.auth is ready, the component will render a spinner
- After props.auth is ready, the component will render your normal app
- Rerendering happens when props are change (ie redux is changed)

Comment: @DavitG - if this helped you I would appreciate if you accept it as the answer.